# hello every one can any body help me to fix this?

Tags: android, eclipse

my problem is when i want to change the name of my button text it gives me the hardcore error and says you should use string in eclipse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.companey.ali.Main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Alireza" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the full error message. And the title you put should describe the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Define button names in res/values/strings.xml. for eg.,

```
<string name="button_text1">Benefits</string>
    <string name="button_text2">Links</string>
```

In your layout file, u can use it as a property of button like this.

```
android:text="@strings/button_text1"
```

If you have to change the text dynamically in the code, use

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(<id_of_the_button>);
    button.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_text1); 
or
   button.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_text2);
```

based on your need. 
Storing the strings in the strings.xml instead of hardcoding will help you when u have to translate to different locale. This maynot be a error, just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to define strings in 'strings.xml' file, it will be available on location res > values > strings.xml

```
<string name="button_text">Alireza</string>
```

Now in your layout file do the following change in button tag

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@strings/button_text" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a suggestion, no an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving you error, it is just giving you warning that in strings.xml file you have to declare strings and use strings inside xml using string xml reference.Either you ignore that warning or do like below.

Go to res folder then to values folder, there you find strings.xml file open that file and inside resources tag do like below :-

```
<string name="alireza">Alireza </string>
```

and inside your xml use it with `@string/alireza` like below

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/alireza" />
```

Comment: can you please send me whole xml where you are using and let me know what type of error it is giving. Send me error showing on xml.